# Изменять скорость анимации при помощи ползунка

Tags: javascript, html, математика, css-animation

коллеги!
Передо мной стоит задача изменять скорость анимации при помощи ползунка и прикрученному к нему событию. В html это выглядит вот так:
`<input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="slider" id="range">`

В js рамках обработчика следующще делается:

```
   let tempSpeed = encode(slider.value);
   document.querySelector('#circle' + val).style.animationDuration = tempSpeed.toString() + 's';
  });
```

Поскольку у нас чем меньше длительности анимации, тем выше скорость, мы в рамках ф-ции encode должны делить значение ползунка на 100, что я и делаю. Но сталкиваюсь с проблемой: скорость должна меняться нелинейно, иначе только на середине шкалы заметно изменение скорость, а на верхних значениях прирост скорости наоборот крайне медленный. Очевидно, надо использовать что-то вроде кривых Безье, я нашёл формулу, но получил неприятный эффект: если в крайне левом положении значение было равно 100, то на втором оно уже равно 50, на третьем - 25 и т.д. То есть плавности никакой. Формула рассчёта, что я использовал такая:
 `let tempSpeed = 100 / (1 - Math.pow(1 - points, 3));`

Забыл упомянуть, что **на выходе ф-ции хочу получать значение от 100 (самая медленная скорость) до 0.1 (самая быстрая скорость).**

Пожалуйста помогите, дайте какие-то ориентиры и строго не судите: в первый раз в жизни описываю поведение элемента, привязанное к шкале.

Comment: А чем вас не устроила гипербола наример?

Comment: Вы знаете, может быть бы и устроила, но я перепробовал с https://easings.net/ru практически все графики, которые примерно мы подходили под мою задачу. И практически на всех вариантах у меня какие-то совершенно дикие данные данные выдавала моя ф-ция. То есть такое ощущение, что не в графике дело, а в том как мне правильно выудить из ф-ции (в т.ч. задействующей формулы с сайта), что я хочу получить, то есть эти самые 100...0.1

Comment: Нарисуйте желаемое поведение, где ускорение а где замедление, будет проще выбрать формулу.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Я его нашёл, но от этого формула не стала выдавать нужные мне значения. Вот то, что мне нужно https://easings.net/ru#easeInOutCubic

Comment: Ну так и используйте ту формулу что там написана, у вас указана совершенно иная функция, сравните :    
`let tempSpeed = 100 * (points < 0.5 ? 4 * points * points * points : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * points + 2, 3) / 2);` и у вас     
`let tempSpeed = 100 / (1 - Math.pow(1 - points, 3));`, найдите 10 отличий как бы... :)

Comment: Вы правы, это был прежний вариант. Нынешний такой: ```function encode(x) {
    let tempSpeed = x < 0.5 ? 4 * x * x * x : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * x + 2, 1) / 2;
    return 100 / tempSpeed;} ``` Тем не менее, моё максимальное значение скорости останавливается на 1, а мне, как я уже писал, нужно 0.1 получить как крайне правое значение на шкале. При том, что min value самого элемента html я пробовал уже делать равным, как нулю, так и единице(

Answer (score 0):

Для плавного изменения скорости можно использовать такую формулу, обеспечивающую логарифмическую зависимость скорости от значения ползунка:

```
let tempSpeed = Math.pow(10, 2 - range.value / range.max * 3);
 // или так:
let tempSpeed = 10 ** (2 - range.value / range.max * 3);
```

При этом получается, что в крайнем левом положении ползунка скорость равна 10 ^ 2 степени, т. е., **100**, а в крайнем правом - 10 ^ -1 степени, т. е., **0.1**

Если нужно наоборот, получить значение ползунка для достижения заданной скорости, можно использовать такой цикл:

```js
let tempSpeed = 23; // задаём скорость
myvalue = null;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
    if(Math.floor(10 ** (2 - tempSpeed / (100 / 3))) == i) myvalue = i;
}
console.log(myvalue); // получаем значение ползунка
```

Comment: а как бы мне в обратную сторону также всё это преобразовать?

Comment: Для этого нужно эту формулу вывернуть на изнанку, но это потребует много времени. Поэтому лучше использовать цикл подбора. Ответ я дополнил